# How can I stop my air drying clay from losing its shape as it dries?

Tags: clay

I am using air dry clay more precisely Thai clay.

How to make sure the shape is not disturb while drying? I had made a cornet shape similar to this one:

[image: Cornet shape]

When I left it to dry overnight the shape distorted and formed a base so that the clay could stand up. However, I don't want it form a base as I want it to keep the circle shape. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a support armature to hold up your sculpture while it dries.

I notice, in your photo, there is something that looks pink icing. That might be how that artist hid where the armature was inserted to hold up their sculpture. After the sculpture dried the armature was removed and the hole that was left behind was hidden by the icing.

Comment: @tyty : you might also consider having the opening down as it dries, rather than on its side like that.

Answer (score -1):

organise the build differently .. like, make five donuts and dry them individually. Once dry use slip to glue them together into the combined shape. Then fire the assembly

Comment: The question is specifically about air-dry clay, which is not fired, and multiple pieces would likely still have the same issue of flattening on one side. With an air-dry material, it would most likely also just look like five pieces glued together instead of one solid piece as shown in the photo.